# Time-based .rolling() fails with group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here's a code snippet from [Pandas Issue #13966](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13966)

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01 09:30:00', periods=20, freq='s')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1] * 20 + [2] * 12 + [3] * 8,
                   'B': np.concatenate((dates, dates)),
                   'C': np.arange(40)})
```

Fails:

```
df.groupby('A').rolling('4s', on='B').C.mean()
ValueError: B must be monotonic
```

Per the issue linked above, this seems to be a bug. Does anyone have a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `B` as the index first so as to use `Groupby.resample` method on it.

```
df.set_index('B', inplace=True)
```

Groupby `A` and resample based on seconds frequency. As resample cannot be directly used with rolling, use `ffill`(forward `fillna` with `NaN` limit as 0).
Now use `rolling` function by specifying the window size as 4 (because of `freq=4s`) interval and take it's mean along `C` column as shown:

```
for _, grp in df.groupby('A'):
    print (grp.resample('s').ffill(limit=0).rolling(4)['C'].mean().head(10)) #Remove head()
```

Resulting output obtained:

```
B
2016-01-01 09:30:00    NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:01    NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:02    NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:03    1.5
2016-01-01 09:30:04    2.5
2016-01-01 09:30:05    3.5
2016-01-01 09:30:06    4.5
2016-01-01 09:30:07    5.5
2016-01-01 09:30:08    6.5
2016-01-01 09:30:09    7.5
Freq: S, Name: C, dtype: float64
B
2016-01-01 09:30:00     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:01     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:02     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:03    21.5
2016-01-01 09:30:04    22.5
2016-01-01 09:30:05    23.5
2016-01-01 09:30:06    24.5
2016-01-01 09:30:07    25.5
2016-01-01 09:30:08    26.5
2016-01-01 09:30:09    27.5
Freq: S, Name: C, dtype: float64
B
2016-01-01 09:30:12     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:13     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:14     NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:15    33.5
2016-01-01 09:30:16    34.5
2016-01-01 09:30:17    35.5
2016-01-01 09:30:18    36.5
2016-01-01 09:30:19    37.5
Freq: S, Name: C, dtype: float64
```

---

***TL;DR***

Use [`groupby.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) as a workaround instead after setting the index appropriately:

```
# tested in version - 0.19.1
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda grp: grp.resample('s').ffill(limit=0).rolling(4)['C'].mean())
```

(Or)

```
# Tested in OP's version - 0.19.0
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda grp: grp.resample('s').ffill().rolling(4)['C'].mean())
```

Both work.

Comment: Why do you set limit=0 within ffill? For instance, if I change freq='2s' in the creation of the original data frame, your example breaks. However, if I change ffill to have no arguments, this seems to work.

Comment: More concretely, I think the correct code is: `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda grp: grp.resample('s').ffill().rolling(4)['C'].mean())`

Comment: Nah, it doesn't break for me. Supplying `limit=0` ensures that no `NaN` elements get padded during the forward fill operation. Maybe it works without assigning an `int` value, as default `limit=None`. But to be on the safer side, just use the arg. Yeah, the last one mentioned is the syntax you're looking for.

Comment: When I say breaks I mean that I get only NaNs in the output. To be clear, this is the output I get when I do limit=0: `B
2016-01-01 09:30:00   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:01   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:02   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:03   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:04   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:05   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:06   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:07   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:08   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:09   NaN`

Comment: All `Nans`! Which version of `pandas` are you in? To check, do: `print (pd.__version__)`

Comment: I am using version 0.19.0

Comment: So you mean to say without providing an arg for `ffill`, you get the right result? Also, there had been issues in the past regarding the usage of `groupby.resampler` and it's API has seen changes on every version released till date.Unfortunately, the docs aren't well documented either. Well, if that's the case, you could use the syntax without the args if you are truly able to get it to work. I'll make a slight edit to my post.

Comment: Correct, not providing an arg for ffill gets the right result for my contrived example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129132/discussion-between-huey-and-nickil-maveli).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df.sort_values('B').set_index('B').groupby('A').rolling('4s').C.mean()
```